# How do I determine the user when my SQL Server Login is a AD group?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Consider this example:

If I have a security group on Active Directory (let's call it `MyGroup`) which has 5 users in it (`MYDOMAIN\User1` - `MYDOMAIN\User5`)

If I create a SQL Server Login and User for my database like this:

```
CREATE LOGIN [MYDOMAIN\MyGroup] FROM WINDOWS;
CREATE USER [MyGroup] FOR LOGIN [MYDOMAIN\MyGroup];
```

If `MYDOMAIN\User4` connects to the database, is there a SQL query I can use to tell which user of `MyGroup` has connected to the database?

Comment: `SELECT CURRENT_USER` returns user of the current session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [SUSER_SNAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx) will return the current login, when called without a parameter.

Example

```
SELECT
    SUSER_SNAME()
;
```